# How can I limit Launchpad to Applications directory

Tags: macos, launchpad

Is there a way to limit Launchpad to show applications only from `Applications` folder?

My launchpad is a mess, I have applications from Python packages which doesn't make sense to appear on Launchpad.

Comment: Just FYI, if you long click an app icon, you can remove it from LaunchPad just like you can on iOS/iPadOS.

Comment: Strange, It only made it rotate on my system.

Comment: I'm away from my desk at the moment, so I'll reconfirm later, but I have rearranged my Launchpad so only the Apps I am most interested in is on the first page, then each page is a category of apps (utilities, productivity, graphics, etc.)

Comment: I can see how to arrange them. I don't see the x from iOS.

Comment: I just verified the workings of this.  The apps that you download from the App store can be removed by long clicking like iOS.  "Normally" installed apps can't be removed this way.  However, I'd still rearrange things to make it a better experience.